# How to sum a hex string

Tags: c

I read a hex String from the user and then I need to calculate the sum of the numbers (by grouping them together) and display the result. I don't understand why the result is not accurate.

```
printf("Enter a string:\n");
char str[38];
scanf("%s", str);

char hex [] = {"00"};
int sum = 0; 
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0, j = 1 ; i < 37, j<38; i ++, j++){
    hex[0]= str[i];
    hex[1] = str[j];
    sum += (int) strtol(hex, NULL, 16);
}
printf("%x", sum);
```

I entered the following String:

137AF00A0D

...which should be calculated like this:
13 + 7A + F0 + 0A + 0A + 0D but the result is 3D8 instead of 19E.

Can you please help me?

Comment: That's the moment when your debugger will help you.

Comment: The end condition for the `for` loop is wrong. You should end the loop when you encounter a NUL character.

Comment: warning in the _for `i < 37, j<38` is equivalent to only `j<38`, it is not `i < 37 && j<38` even this is not the problem in the current case. However it is also useless to use 2 indexes, only one is enough

Comment: I encourage you to replace your _scanf_ with `scanf("%37s", str);` to not take the risk to write out of _str_ in case the input string is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iteration is needlessly obscure and also incorrect. You only need one iterator, but you should increase it by 2 each lap in the loop, since you examine 2 characters. Simplify the code into this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[] = "AABBCCDD";
  char hex[3] = {'\0'};

  unsigned int sum = 0; 
  unsigned int length = strlen(str);
  for (int i = 0; i<length; i+=2)
  {
    hex[0] = str[i];
    hex[1] = str[i+1];
    sum += strtol(hex, NULL, 16);
  }
  printf("%x", sum);
}
```

Notably this has no error handling for wrong amount of nibbles, incorrect characters etc.

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
  char hex[] = { "00" };

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i += 2) {
    hex[0] = str[i];
    hex[1] = str[i + 1];
    sum += (int)strtol(hex, NULL, 16);
  }
  printf("%x", sum);
```

Keep it simple, and don't make it more complicated than necessary.

1. you don't need two indexes
2. your end condition is wrong, you want to stop at the end of the input string, not at the end of the input buffer.

Comment: @xing Odd number of characters doesn't make sense. Should `"ABC"` give `0xAB + 0xC` or `0xA + 0xBC`? If this isn't defined, you can't allow odd number of characters.

Comment: @xing You can check the user input string length % 2, then give an error message.

Comment: @xing actually after a second thought having a odd number of chars doesn't really make sense. What would sum would you get with `"111"`?